# neo4j as a product recommendation tool

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm currently experimenting with neo4j (v1.9.2) as a product recommendation tool.

The model is quite simple with a few transactions, each associated with products using the 'CONTAINS' relationship.

Given a product the following cypher query returns the recommended products included in other transactions.

```
START product=node(3)
MATCH product-[:CONTAINS]-otherTransaction-[:CONTAINS]->other_product
WHERE product <> other_product
RETURN other_product.number AS productCode,
COUNT(other_product) AS ranking
ORDER BY ranking DESC
```

The query works as expected returning the other recommended products, however, for a large data set it is extremely slow!  Using the JavaAPI approach instead of cypher does not make much of a difference.  Even using the neo4j server caused out.of.memory issues.

I would greatly appreciate some suggestions as how to proceed with the performance issue.

1. Is there a multi-threaded approach to traversing the graph?
2. How could I break the above cypher query to multiple sub-queries and then collate the answer?
3. Instead of trying to get to all the nodes, that are associated with the starting product, should the traversing approach be changed?

Comment: How large is large? How slow is slow? How many nodes are in your graph and how many relationships do each of the products contain? Is it just the first run that is slow, or is it still slow if you run the query multiple times?

Comment: Hi Bill, I started looking at about 600,000 lines of record, which map to about 28,000 nodes  with 600K relationships.  Some products occur in about 20 transactions, whereas, more common ones appear in about 3000 cases.  Even with the big data, finding the number of transactions that contain a given product seems to be fine.  It's the second part of determining the recommended products that is slow (ie after running for 30 minutes, you still don't get a result).  I haven't had a complete first run yet.  Regards, Shiraz

Comment: Hi, have you tryed reco4j? It is has a plugin for neo4j that allow you to starting recommend in few minutes. Have a look at it: http://www.reco4j.org

Comment: Grazie Alessandro.  No, I still have not investigated reco4j.  I'll give it a try, thanks.  My understanding is that, reco4j is based on top of neo4j and hence may have the same performance issues that I am experiencing with big data.  Regards, Shiraz

Comment: Is it at all possible to use neo4j purely for a recommendation engine for big data? If yes, then do I have to traverse the graph and load the data in-memory beforehand to speed up subsequent searches? Or do I have to revisit the model structure. Currently, I have a transaction T1 with a number of products, P1 and P2, (outgoing paths to products).  If neo4j is not suitable then, yes, I would consider looking at reco4j. Where does Gremlin fit into this? Would it be faster than Cypher for what I'm planning to query? Thanks, Shiraz

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between reco4j approach and direct query on neo4j is that in our software we build a model of the data and we store new information that allow to speed up the recommendation process. On the other side a certain amount of time is required to create the model, but after that you should be able to perform prediction in milliseconds.